# Any other machine learning algorithms besides clustering for Customer Segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, marketing

I've searched online materials for Customer Segmentation for a while. Most materials are related with K-means or some other clustering algorithms. Are there any other machine learning or statistical models that are widely used in industry for Customer Segmentation? Any tutorials or related links are helpful.

Comment: Have you heard of RMF analysis?

Comment: Just searched the RMF analysis term. This is very helpful!